# Disable MSI extensions on Magento Enterprise 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2.3, magento2-enterprise

I'm trying to disable MSI extensions on Magento enterprise version 2.4.5-p1. I'm using below command for this:

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryRequisitionList Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventoryBundleImportExport Magento_InventoryBundleProductIndexer Magento_InventoryInStorePickupApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickup Magento_InventoryInStorePickupGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuoteGraphQl Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSales Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesApi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupQuote Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend Magento_InventoryInStorePickupMultishipping Magento_InventoryInStorePickupSalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryInStorePickupWebapiExtension Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi Magento_InventorySwatchesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryVisualMerchandiser Magento_InventoryWishlist
```

I disabled all the extensions properly and able to compile and deploy content without any issues. However, when I try to place order, on checkout page I'm getting below error in console and can't place the order.

```
[2023-01-04 05:36:29] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend/shipping-information" template requested by "checkout.sidebar.shipping-information".
```

Please see attached image for reference.

I'm not sure why its still rendering template from Magento_InventoryInStorePickupFrontend as it is already disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fix it by following below steps:

- Re-enabled MSI extensions, setup:di:compile, reindex, flush cache
- Add default inventory source and stock at Stores->Source and Stores->Stock
- Tried placing order and it worked
- Disabled MSI extensions again, setup:di:compile, reindex, flush cache
- Again tried placing order and it worked without any issues

FYI, this instance was upgraded from enterprise 2.1.9, so it doesn't have MSI modules previously and hence needed to add source/stock first.

I'm not sure if this is a correct fix but this solved my issue.